# declval<T> vs declval<T&>

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I'm trying to understand the difference between `declval<T>()` and `declval<T&>()`? Is there an example where `T&` can be used while `T` cannot?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct X {
  X() = delete;
  int func();
};

int main()
{
// works with both X as well as X& within declval
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<X&>().func()), int>);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from ref-qualified member functions (which are used rarely), a more common use-case for `std::declval<T&>()` is to create an lvalue reference (it creates an rvalue-reference otherwise).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct X {};

int func(X&);

int main() {
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(func(std::declval<X&>())), int>); // works
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(func(std::declval<X>())), int>); // error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an example where `T&` can be used while `T` cannot?

Yes, for example in situations like this where you have ref-qualified overloads:

```
struct X {
    X() = delete;
    int func() &;
    double func() &&;
};

int main() {
    // this static_assert would fail:
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(std::declval<X>().func()), int>);
}
```